# I have tried everything , every technique , but i am unable to send gmail from my xampp server?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, email, gmail

My functionality is like , user register his account and email should be send to him to activate his account . user click that link in his email and get his account activated.

i changed `php.ini` in various ways : e.g i changed `sendmail.php`

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465 //i also changed it to 587 to test
auth_username=me@gmail.com
auth_password=mypassword
force_sender=me@gmail.com
hostname=smtp.gmail.com //i tried it by leaving it blank

I changed my php.ini to this and close my apache , th i restart it to configure . 
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
 smtp_port = 465   //i changed it 587 as well 
sendmail_path="\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\"-t"
```

I turned my antivirus off , i am using php 5.6.3 and xampp server 3.2.1 , I m using window 7 home premium.

My php code here .
I m using this line of function in `register_user`.

```
 email($register_data['email'],'Active your account',"\n\n hello".$register_data['first_name']. ",you need to activate your account below:\n\n http:/localhost/lr/active.php?email=" .$register_data['email']."email_code=".$register_data['email_code']." \n\n  -auto hire edge");
I m using this function to send mail

function email($to, $subject, $body)
{
    mail($to , $subject , $body, 'From: hello@gmail.com');

}
```

Please tell if i m doing something wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO7MfDcM-Ho)
link:It is a video tutorial and it will help you configure your localhost xampp server to send gmail.

Comment: I followed , but not working ! no error in my code or integrtion but i m unable to send mail yet